# How does `autoreconf` create m4/ folder?

Tags: autoconf, autoreconf

I hit [a problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65828592/the-problem-with-configure-file-in-the-docker-image-under-gitlab-ci) - and I detected the very strange situation:

1. I run Docker image locally and run there `autoreconf -i` and I get correct and robust `./configure` script.
2. Then I run `autoreconf -i` in the same Docker image but under Gitlab CI. And I get broken `./configure` script - some of M4 macro were not substituted to their shell code, so Bash cannot execute them and treats them as syntax errors.

The difference is in `m4/` folder in the both runs: successful `m4/` folder contains files like:

```
aria2_arg.m4
ax_check_compile_flag.m4
ax_cxx_compile_stdcxx_11.m4
codeset.m4
fallocate.m4
fcntl-o.m4
gettext.m4
... # and so on
```

but in the failed (Gitlab CI) `m4/` folder there are:

```
gettext.m4
fcntl-o.m4
# ... and so on
```

and `aria2_arg.m4`, `ax_check_compile_flag.m4`, `ax_cxx_compile_stdcxx_11.m4`, `fallocate.m4` and others are missing. I don't know how is it possible if the Docker image is the same in both cases, but... **how does `autoreconf` create `m4/` folder? If its content's source is the Docker image itself (I don't know is it true, it's my suggestion only), then why is the content different in both cases?**

Answer (score 0):

No any magic. The missing m4 files do exist in the original Aria2 Github repository (in `m4/`) folder. `autoreconf -i` adds another .m4 files to this folder. But it has `.gitignore` with .m4 rule. I added it to another git repo (to build it in Gitlab) but `m4/` folder was ignored. So:

```
 Aria2   ->   local folder   ->   run docker ->     OK
Github          with m4/            locally      m4/ exists
```

works fine, but:

```
Aria2   ->  another git repo   ->   run Gitlab CI ->      Failure
Github        (now no m4/)                             (.m4 missing)
```

So, it seems the reason of the problem was - the miss of `m4/` in the second git repo (at least I have got the first successful build)